# Twitter4j BlockingQueue.queue gives nullpointer exception when used with axis 2 jars

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-hbc

I am trying to use the twitter4j API for consuming the streaming API for twitter. It is working perfecting fine until i have added few axis 2 libraries.

Code:

```
BlockingQueue<String> queue = twitter.getBlockingQueue();
        //Infinite loop to always receive the messages
        while (true) {
            String twitterServerReply = null;
            try{
                twitterServerReply = queue.take();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
```

Following is the exception i am getting:

```
Exception in thread "hosebird-client-io-thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.RestartableHttpClient.getConnectionManager(RestartableHttpClient.java:83)
at com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase.run(ClientBase.java:165)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here is my POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
<artifactId>hbc-example</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Hosebird Client Examples</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbc-core</artifactId> <!-- or hbc-twitter4j -->
        <version>2.2.0</version> <!-- or whatever the latest version is -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>[4.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have to use AXIS 2 as i need to consume some SOAP webservices.
Can anyone please help-out to check if with which dependencies i might be getting the issue?

NOTE: It works perfectly fine if i remove all the axis 2 dependency.

Comment: Any help on this, does axis 2 instantiate a thread for AtomicReference<HttpClient>? Getting nullpointer while getting a connection for org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager in hbc-twitter.

Comment: Following dependency is causing the issue:

    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
  </dependency>    

If this is commented, the twitter hbc, streaming works fine, but i get a deployment exception while alling axis 2 webservice. This is a required dependency and cannot comment it,

Need some help over this